# variable x satisfies interface A and optionally also staisfies interface B

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have the following declaration:

```
const x : A | (A & B)
```

I'm wondering if there is an "optional" variant of the & operator so that I could more consisely write

```
const x : A &? B
```

to signify that x definitely satisfies `A`, but also perhaps sometimes `B`.

Comment: I'm curious what you're doing with `A | (A & B)`? it's just that `A  | (A & B)` doesn't enforce that `x` has to have all of `B`'s properties if it has any of them. `x` could have just one of `B`'s properties and still be valid, since that's an `A` with an excess property (which just happens to be one of `B`'s properties).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder later in my code I'd have a runtime check to see if `x` also satisfies `B`, and if it does I'll use `x as B` there. If I declare `x`'s type only as `A` then (1) I mislead the reader of the code, even if it doesn't have any typing benefits, and (2) typescript sometimes complains while type-casting `x as B` that `B` and `A` "do not sufficiently overlap", and then I have to instead do `x as unknown as B`.

Comment: Thanks! If you don't mind taking a minute, I'd be keen to see an example of (2). Just for my greater understanding of TypeScript. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder a trivial example : [link to typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1oDMCWAnCAXAcmALYCm0AXNHlhgHYDm0APtAK60AmJmtJHA3EgC+SJAHox0YAHsiABwwgSWaPQwA3EjDC1oyrNKxIZtPNDAU40ALzRarECHMxYgiXel6sBo+5NmAI0t4W3tHZzZaAGtaaQB3XUg4QSA)

Comment: Thanks. I meant of how `A | (A & B)` vs. just `A` lets you avoid type assertions sometimes. I thought [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+QBwEYAuZEAVwFsAjaAbhz3wCZSKb6sBfLUSWRCgBCmRrnwBmNlVpQGeAgBZpHOdyxYAJhAQAbOFBS6IYZAA9SqBgHprybXoNGT5y8gA+yABToAZMiEASgYsGHIQBDBgAHsQZAgzOEp8Yy9qUiDRBQRYgGdo4wA6XWiAcy8AAwASDGpCyS4AGmQauvxFLgrg9V4YbwAiSX7kUHNArLwEpJSILzNuriA) would be an example of what you were saying, but was very surprised that it worked with just `A`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Utility Types

There is no such syntax as `A &? B` and no way to define a syntax.  What we do have are [utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html).

You can define a utility type for anything, though it might end being more characters than just writing out `A | (A & B)`, depending on how you name it.

```
type WithOptional<Required, Optional> = Required | ( Required & Optional )
```

```
const x: WithOptional<A, B> = ...
```

#### Moving the &

If instead of `A` and `B` we have `SomeLongName` and `SomeOtherLongName`, then having to write the `A` type twice in `A | (A & B)` suddenly becomes a lot more annoying.  `A` is present in both members of the union, so we can extract it out and say that we always have `A` and also have either `B` or nothing added to it.

```
const x: A & (B | {});
const y: SomeLongName & (SomeOtherLongName | {});
```

#### Partial

There was some discussion in the comments about the potential use case for this type.  My use cases for this sort of thing usually have to do with destructuring and `A | (A & B)` would not allow destructuring of `B` properties.  So what I end up writing is `A & Partial<B>`.  This says that all `A` properties are required and all `B` properties are optional.  `B` properties can be destructured but might be `undefined`.

```
const x: A & Partial<B> = { p1: 0, p2: 0 }

// p1 and p2 are `number`, p3 and p4 are `number | undefined`
const { p1, p2, p3, p4 } = x;
```

You could also use this definition for a utility type:

```
type WithOptional<Required, Optional> = Required & Partial<Optional>
```

Comment: Thanks for not only answering the question, but also providing an exhaustive list of alternatives which might address the same need.